# Has it been observed that the dihydrogen molecule dissociates into ions?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, molecular-orbital-theory, valence-bond-theory

As we know from the improved methods valence bond theory (VB), as well as molecular orbital theory (MO-LCAO), the wave function of the $\ce{H2}$ molecule consist of two terms, which belong to covalent and ion structure, respectively:
$$\psi =\psi_\mathrm{cov} + \lambda\psi_\mathrm{ion}.$$

According to quantum mechanics, there is a nonzero probability $\propto\lambda^2$ for the ionic state wave-function term. Such reaction should lead to the $\ce{H2}$ molecule dissociation products $\ce{H+}$ (proton) and anion $\ce{H-}$:
$$\ce{H2 -> H+ + H-}.$$

Have such processes been observed in nature?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Surely<sup>1</sup>. At the end of the day, it is just the matter of supplying enough energy: the homolysis requires approximately 4.5 eV per hydrogen molecule, while for heterolysis more than 17 eV per molecule must be provided.

---

1) G. Busca, A. Vaccari, Heterolytic dissociation of hydrogen on high-temperature methanol synthesis catalysts, Journal of Catalysis, 108(2), 1987, 491-494, http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0021-9517(87)90198-9.